# Xcode: Product archive is not appearing under the archive section for uploading the app to App store

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building and archiving an app to upload it to the App store. I could build and archive the app in the Xcode. But the archive is not appearing in the list. Following is what I have done so far.

I have the set the version and build number under the General tab.

[image]

Then I have also set up the Team and app identifier and other information required under the Signing & Capabilities tab.

Then I set the Generic IOS device for Simulator.

Then I archive the app.

[image]

The build was successful without any issue. But when I go to the Window -> Organiser, I cannot find the archive as follow. There is no archive for the app at all.

[image]

I looked up for the solution and I tried setting the Skip install to NO as follow and archived again.

[image]

Still, the archive is not appearing. It is working for the other app. Not for this app. What could be the possible reason and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. After setting the Skip install options, I needed to restart the XCode.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Spotlight has not indexed the archive. Look to see if the archive is on the filesystem and then open it from the command line:

```
open ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2020-11-04/appname\ 11-4-20,\ 12.48 PM.xcarchive
```

The `open` command will cause archive to be opened by Xcode Organizer.

If it still isn't showing, but the archive is definitely on the filesystem, look at `Products` directory inside the archive. There should only be a single product, which is in `Applications/yourapp.app`. If there is more than one thing under `Products` then you will need to figure out what else is there and stop it from being copied there during the archive process. Many times it will be some other framework, and you can prevent it from being installed into the archive by enabling the `SKIP_INSTALL` flag for the framework.